# classList.remove is removing elements from a HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering some very strange behaviour with JavaScripts new classList API, say we have the following HTML code:

```
<p class="testing">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p class="testing">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

And the following JavaScript code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testing");
alert(elements.length);
elements[0].classList.remove("testing");
alert(elements.length);
```

The first alert will give you a value of 2, whilst the second alert returns 1.

It appears that removing the class from the element is also removing it from the `elements` HTMLCollection, which makes absolutely no sense to me.

You can see an example of this code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rE79n/1/).

I encountered this problem when trying to remove a certain class from some elements using code like below:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('testing');
var elementsLength = elements.length - 1;
for(var i = 0; i <= elementsLength ; i++)
{
    elements[i].classList.remove('testing');
}
```

Say we have two elements like in the example above, the loop runs successfully the first time, but the second time it's looking for an element in the HTMLCollection that no longer exists, so I get something like "TypeError: elements[i] is undefined".

You can see an example of the above code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2MU57/)

This is frustrating to say the least, I can't understand why/how classList.remove could effect what is effectively an array set only once before the classList.remove function is called. I can't even seem to find anything about this behaviour online.

Am I doing something crazy? Or has I unearthed some strange hidden feature of the classList api that no one knows about?

Comment: It's good that you cached the `.length` property in `elementsLength` for the loop.  With a normal array this is good practice and will give you a small speed boost, but with a `HTMLCollection` it is [particularly important for performance](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/02/03/speed-up-your-javascript-part-4/) due to it's "live" nature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The collection returned by `document.getElementsByClassName` is live so if an element doesn't have that class anymore it will be removed from the collection.

You can either create a non-live copy of the collection:

```
var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('testing'));
```

Or take in account that it's live:

```
while (elements.length) elements[0].classList.remove('element-focus');
```

Comment: I never realised that `document.getElementsByClassName` worked like this ... does this mean that it's effectively called whenever the dom is manipulated? Or does it only run when an element that belongs to it is altered?

Comment: @SeanDunwoody I am not sure what is the underlying implementation that keeps the collection in sync with the DOM, however taken from MDN "HTMLCollections in the HTML DOM are live; they are automatically updated **when the underlying document is changed**.".

Comment: Most if not all DOM methods return live HTMLCollection objects like this.

Comment: @UselessCode I disagree, `querySelectorAll` doesn't for instance. Which other common used DOM method returns live collections?

Comment: @plalx I should have said "many" instead of "most". In addition to `.getElementsByClassName`, the [`.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) and [`.getElementsByTagNameNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagNameNS) methods return live lists.
The [`.children` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) and [.childNodes property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) also return live lists.

Answer (score 4):

Using `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection):

> An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.

Thus (as described in [plalx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108234/3345375)) if you remove an element's class, the element is removed from an HTMLCollection based on that class.

Instead you could use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a static NodeList collection:

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

So your code would change from

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testing");
```

with the class name `"testing"` as an argument, to

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".testing");
```

with the class selector `".testing"` as an argument.

And then you could iterate over `elements` which would be a static NodeList.